# Is there any benefit to compiling back end of a split Access DB?

Tags: ms-access

The performance analyzer in Access 2016 suggests that I compile my back-end DB file.

Is this just a generic recommendation or are there benefits to compiling the back-end?

Would I then need to re-link my tables to the compiled version?

Comment: Does it have any modules, e.g. support functions for queries? If it has only tables, then there is nothing to compile.

Comment: It's a true back-end with only tables. You can add that as an answer.

Comment: Right, nothing to compile, but I have seen backend file size reduce after C&R. Review http://accessjitsu.com/2017/01/25/microsoft-access-vba-to-compact-and-repair/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that all code executes on the client side, then no advantage exists.

I would likely leave it as a standard accDB, as this will suggest that the file in question is data file, and not application code.

So while the regular maintains of a compact and repair is still recommended, compiling the back end is likely a bad idea, as this could interfere with different versions of Access using the back end. With linked tables, it is perfect legal to have different versions of the front end link to the back end. I thus recommend against compiling the back end.